# Payment - Website Payment Standard Vs Express Checkout Vs Adaptive Payments

Tags: paypal, checkout, payment-processing

I'm trying to figure out the difference between **Website Payment Standard**, **Express Checkout** and **Adaptive Payments**. So far as I know, Payment Standard allows user to pay using credit card(without Paypal account). Express Checkout seems like has all the features as Payment Standard. Adaptive payment can send single payment to mulitple receivers.

With online documentation, I'm getting confused in comparing this three payment-processing, they just sound like do all the same thing.

Can someone please explain more about their difference like checkout flow and pros/cons ? And some example of when it's use. Thank you :)

Comment: *Express Checkout* is a product that allows **receiving** money from shoppers, *Adaptive Payments* is a product that allows **sending** funds.